# Processing csv file with more than 700K rows of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a .csv file (around 400MB in size) which contains 700K rows of structured data.
Table structure is:

```
+----+----------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+
| Id | Category | List1 |   List2   | Value1 | Value2 |
+----+----------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+
|  1 |        1 | A,B,C | Cat1,Cat2 |    100 |      5 |
|  2 |        1 | D,F   | Cat1,Cat4 |    120 |      4 |
|  3 |        2 | E,A   | Cat3      |    140 |      2 |
|  4 |        2 | E,A   | NULL      |    110 |      3 |
|  5 |        3 | B     | Cat2      |    100 |      6 |
+----+----------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

For each row (CurrentRow) of the table I want to calculate:
CurrentRow.Value3 = SUM(Value1)/SUM(Value2) of all other rows (OtherRow) in the table where the following conditions are met:

```
Condition1 = CurrentRow.Category != OtherRow.Category
Condition2 = CurrentRow.List1 intersects OtherRow.List1  
Condition3 = CurrentRow.List2 intersects OtherRow.List2 or CurrentRow.List2 = NULL or OtherRow.List2 = NULL
```

Also, I want to list Ids of rows which where involved into calculation of Value3.

Example for first row:
**Condition1**: first row has category value 1. As a result, rows 3-4 meet consition #1 because their category values are not equal to 1.
**Condition2**: column "List1" has values "A,B,C" which intersects with values "E,A" (*row #3*), "E,A" (*row #4*), "B" (*row #5*).
**Condition3**: Column "List2" has values "Cat1,Cat2" which intersects with values "Cat1,Cat4" (*row #2*), "Cat2" (*row #5*) and also we take *row #4* as it has "NULL" value.

As a result, we take rows #4 and #5 as they both meet all conditions.
Value3 = (110+100)/(3+6) = 210/9 = 23.33
Ids = "4,5"

The result for table above would be:

```
+----+----------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------+
| Id | Category | List1 |   List2   | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Ids  |
+----+----------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------+
|  1 |        1 | A,B,C | Cat1,Cat2 |    100 |      5 | 23.33  | 4,5  |
|  2 |        1 | D,F   | Cat1,Cat4 |    120 |      4 | NULL   | NULL |
|  3 |        2 | E,A   | Cat3      |    140 |      2 | NULL   | NULL |
|  4 |        2 | E,A   | NULL      |    110 |      3 | 20     | 1    |
|  5 |        3 | B     | Cat2      |    100 |      6 | 20     | 1    |
+----+----------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+------+
```

I have tried to do it using pandas in python:

```py
data = pd.read_pickle('data.df')
for _index, _record in data.iterrows():
    category = _record["Category"]
    list1 = _record["List1"]
    list2 = _record["list2"]
    candidates = data.loc[(data['Category'] != category) & (pd.Series(list1).isin(data["List1"]).any()) & ((pd.Series(list2).isin(data["List2"]).any()) | (data["List2"][0] == 'NULL') | (list2[0] == 'NULL'))]
    value1_sum = candidates["Value1"].sum()
    value2_sum = candidates["Value2"].sum()
    ids = candidates[['Id']].to_numpy()
    if value2_sum > 0:
        data.loc[_index, "Value3"] = value1_sum/ value2_sum
        data.loc[_index, "Ids"] = ids
data.to_csv('result.csv')
```

It works for small number of rows, but takes forever on 700K rows.
Is there any method to optimize this algorithm?

Comment: Have you tried to split the data set? Then you could apply the operations to each of the datasets and then concatenate them at the end.

Comment: @MachineLearner I am afraid this approach will not work. That is because if I will split the data set, information would become partitioned and useless to calculate Value3 which requires the whole dataset to be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main time-consumer will be the fact that you are iterating over 700,000 rows, one-by-one.

You could perhaps do a few of your checks/comparisons (used in the line with bit-wise stuff: `&`, `|` etc) to begin with, **for all** rows. So for that row, it looks like this now:

```
data.loc[
    (data['Category'] != category) & 
    (pd.Series(list1).isin(data["List1"]).any()) & 
    (pd.Series(list2).isin(data["List2"]).any()) |
    (data["List2"][0] == 'NULL') |
    (list2[0] == 'NULL'))]
```

Before the loop, you could pre-compute each of those rows, adding the results for each comparison as a new columns:

```
data["check1"] = data['Category'] != category
data["check2"] = ...
data["check3"] = ...
data["check4"] = ...
data["check5"] = data.List2 == "NULL"
```

Now use those columns' values in your line with all comparisons.

---

To gain a better understanding of what it taking up all the time, you could [*profile* the code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html), e.g. using the [CProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) module. You could just run over the first 100 rows of your data for that purpose - the profiling tool will give summary statistics.

---

If you really want to get stuck into it, check out [**tha Pandas performance improvement methods**](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#enhancing-performance), which get into using Numba and Cython. There can be huge gains here, but you need to maybe invest a little more effort. [**Numba**](https://numba.pydata.org/index.html) would be the easiest to begin with; unless you are experienced with C-languages.